# Pandas doesn't read a csv correctly

Tags: python, pandas, csv, tensorflow, keras

I'm new to pandas and keras, and i'm trying to build a network to generate word embeddings. I'm following this [guide](https://www.depends-on-the-definition.com/guide-to-word-vectors-with-gensim-and-keras/), trying to adapt it to my specific dataset. I should select some columns from my [dataset](https://dbs.uni-leipzig.de/en/research/projects/object_matching/benchmark_datasets_for_entity_resolution) (DBLP-ACM, you can download it here) for further text elaboration, but pandas doesn't work as expected.

I already tried with the same syntax of the guide i linked above, but pandas puts every column in a single big column (with a weird name: ['id,"title","authors","venue","year";;;;;']). Needless to say, a lot of rows show errors like

`line 393: expected 7 fields, saw 11`

I also tried other solutions like

`quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE`

`engine = "python"`

but nothing works as expected. Basically, i don't understand why this dataset seems malformed (since it looks ok opening it with a csv viewer) and how can i read it correctly using pandas, to submit it to the next part of the program.

**EDIT:** As i pointed out in the comments, i did something wrong splitting my dataset (for training and test) and it went malformed in the process. Fyi, i simply used an online csv splitter. The accepted solution works flawlessly for the original dataset.

Comment: Try passing `engine = "python"` into the function call of your `pandas.read_csv()`. Does that make a difference?

Comment: I have a `Skipping line 1: ',' expected after '"'` on every single line. Still, it's a difference.

Comment: Not entirely sure what your error is. Try pasting the error?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/SX8eFFvF here is the complete error. It skips every line in the dataset, simply (there are 1400 rows because i splitted the dataset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = pd.read_csv("DBLP2.csv", sep=",", quotechar="\"", encoding="latin_1")
```

This worked for me. You haven't provided any example code and I don't know why it isn't working for you.

Comment: After some investigation, seems like your solution works. I splitted the original csv in 2 different csvs (training and test). With this solution i still have the errors on the splitted csv, but not on the original. I probably did something wrong while splitting it. Any advice about it?

Comment: I would bet you are now mixing newlines. You should read in your dataframe, sample it, and then output it with `.to_csv()` instead of using terrible windows text editors or excel or whatever.

Comment: I splitted the data in a different way and everything is working now. Thanks again! The previous error (which i had on the original files) was probably caused by the quotes or the encoding.